# src\App.js 'nav' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't create navbar in reactjs.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Home from './Routes/Home'
import About from './Routes/About'
import Contact from './Routes/Contact'
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import nav from './nav'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <BrowserRouter>
      <nav/>
      
      <Routes>
      <Route>
      
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={<Contact/>} />
      </Route>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

nav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function nav(){
    return <div>
      <nav>
          <Link to="/" >Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about" >About</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" >Contact</Link>
      </nav>

    </div>
}

export default nav
```

The terminals shows
"*Compiled with warnings.
src\App.js
Line 7:8:  'nav' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.

To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.*"

Comment: By convention, React components should be Uppercase.

Comment: I think `element={<Home/>}` should be `component={Home}` (and the next two lines need much the same change).

Comment: @RockySims That's for a new version of React Router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<nav/>` is a valid HTML tag, so ESLint thinks your JSX is referencing that HTML tag, and not the variable that holds the component you imported.

I recommend renaming your component to be `Nav` to remove all ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs,

> A variable foo is considered to be used if any of the following are true:
>
> It is called (foo()) or constructed (new foo())
>
> It is read (var bar = foo)
>
> It is passed into a function as an argument (doSomething(foo))
>
> It is read inside of a function that is passed to another function (doSomething(function() { foo(); }))

So that, said, you maybe be missing some parsing so your valid jsx and reactjs syntax can be valid eslint syntax:

[eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react)

Answer (score 1):

This happenes because your compiler does not recognize JSX syntax as being used.

So, You have to install:
`npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`

Then in your `.eslintrc.json` file you should add `react/jsx-uses-react`

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities where you may have been wrong :-

1. React shows this error because whenever someone declares a variable but didn't use it. In your case you didn't use this nav in your entire App.js file.

```
import nav from './nav'
```

2. You have forgotten to start the `<nav>`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <BrowserRouter>
      <nav/>
      
      <Routes>
      <Route>
      
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={<Contact/>} />
      </Route>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

3. Or custom components in react always start with a captial letter,
   Not like this

```
<nav> <nav/>
```

But like this

```
<Nav> <Nav/>
```